# Using Vue Draggable with a computed Array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using the vuedraggable component from here: https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable

I'm setting it up like this:

```
<draggable v-model="filteredItems">
  <div class="item" v-for="item in filteredItems">{{item.name}}</div>
</draggable>
```

`filteredItems` is a computed property setup like this:

```
computed: {
  get: function() {
   return this.items.filter(item => {
     if(item.category_id == this.activeCategory.id) return true;
   })
  },
  set: function(newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);  // This new value is the new data I want.
    return newValue;
  }
}
```

I thought returning the `newValue` would set the data correctly, but it's just reverting back to it's old value as soon as the drag and drop is complete.

This works great on non-computed variables, and the data in `newValue` is exactly what I need, I'm not fully understanding how to set the computed property to the `newValue`

Any ideas? I've tried several ways to reset the computed property but none of them are working.

Answer (score 4):

Returning the new value will not (re)set the `data` item, but setting the "local" item (in your case, the `items`) to it, will.

```js
computed: {
  filteredItems: {
    // the getter

    set(newValue) {
      // This line
      this.items = newValue;
    }
  }
  
}
```

P.S. Had to remove my previous <s>sily</s> answer. I must be drunk to have missed the fact that the local items are already in the `data` to filter from!

Comment: Yeah that's working great now, I thought if I updated this.items it would remove the non-filtered items but it's not doing that, I guess I don't completely understand how the setter works but it's working now

Comment: @Jordash It will not remove them, that's why I mentioned about "local" data, the computed ones being the copies.